# Can scala hide state in function like scheme's "count" since it have closure too?

Tags: scala, scheme

《The scheme programming language》4th:

```
(define count
 (let ([next 0])
  (lambda ()
   (let ([v next])
    (set! next (+ next 1))
    v))))
```

it hide state in the count using the closure,aovid the “global variable”。It seems scala support closure too,so how to do this in scala?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```scala
val count: () => Int = {
//def count(): Int
  var next = 0
  () => {
    val v = next
    next += 1
    v
  }
}
```

?

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/cFKKUqAjQaeFuBNos1OIvw

https://onecompiler.com/racket/3z5whfdkx

FP style would be

```
def count(): Int = {
  def loop(next: Int, v: Int): Int = v
  val next = 0
  loop(next + 1, next)
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/cFKKUqAjQaeFuBNos1OIvw/1

Comment: I want to know why this can't work:def count = {
  var next = 0
  () => {
    next += 1
    next
  }
} while this in f# can work:let generateStamp =
let mutable count = 0
(fun () -> count <- count + 1; count) they look the seem!

Comment: @wangkai What do you mean exactly by "not work"? How do you check that? What is the difference between Scala and F# code?

Comment: the scala code:def count = { var next = 0 () => { next += 1 next } } when run the function count,it always got 1,but it seems same to the f# code

Comment: @wangkai You're right, the Scala code produces 1 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/Q1o4wXUBQMeEORqJgII1LA But my understanding is that the F# code produces 1 too https://onecompiler.com/fsharp/3z6tmbyjg Right? So do you still have a question here or have we resolved all confusions?

Comment: the f# code will got 1 2 3 when run generateStamp three times.this example is from 《expert f# 4.0》.I think scala implement closure different from scheme and f#.I have no confusions,just found it.Thanks very much!

Comment: @wangkai Yeah, https://onecompiler.com/fsharp/3z6vhjhpg I see now what you meant, thanks. In Scala a `var` is re-created every time, so `var` from different calls are unrelated https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/Q1o4wXUBQMeEORqJgII1LA/2 To have similar behavior in Scala we would need to extract the `var` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/Q1o4wXUBQMeEORqJgII1LA/3